# Problem controlling windows service through an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-services, batch-file

I've an .net 3.5 aspx page which executes a batch file.
The batch file starts and stops a locally running .net Windows WCF service.

When i run this page in a test environment, it works fine.But it does not in other environments.
So, looks like the IIS does not have enough privileges to control this service in those envs.

How do i get this working?

Here is the C# code which runs the batch file:

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
                si.CreateNoWindow = true;
                si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                si.FileName = myBatchFile;
                si.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = si;

                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer at

[How to Start/Stop a Windows Service from an ASP.NET app - Security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818512/how-to-start-stop-a-windows-service-from-an-asp-net-app-security-issues)